# how to set in localstoage?

Tags: javascript, html

where is going wrong to set localstorage book item?
html:

```
<li id="pitaka_confic">Set the book list in main interface </li>
          <input class="pitaka" type="radio" name="pitaka" value="pali" checked="checked"> Hindi
          <input class="pitaka" type="radio" name="pitaka" value="bengali">Bengali
          <input class="pitaka" type="radio" name="pitaka" value="english">English
```

javascript:

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('.book')
     for(var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
          var val = radios[i].value
          radios[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
            localStorage.setItem('bookid', radios[i].value)
          })

        }
```

Comment: You don't have class `book`.

Comment: it should also be radios.length not radio.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have any items of class `book`. They are of class `pitaka`.

Secondly, you're using the same function all the time - so it'd be easier to simply do:

```
const function = event => localStorage.setItem("bookid", element.target.value);
```

And thirdly, you have `var radios` but you're using `radio.length`. Here's some refactored code:

```
const clickFunc = event => localStorage.setItem("bookid", event.target.value);

var radios = document.querySelectorAll(".pitaka");

for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {

    radios[i].addEventListener("click", clickFunc);

}
```

Comment: Event handlers receive the event object, not the emitting element.

Comment: My bad @NiettheDarkAbsol - I think it's fixed.